# Duplicate Validation on Combined Fields in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Hi there I have a table in which combination of three fields is `unique`. I want to put the check of duplication on this combination. Table looks like

[image]

I know how to validate single field, But how to validate the combination is not know. To validate one field I use the following function

```
public function isValid($data) {

    // Options for name field validation
    $options = array(
        'adapter' => Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
        'table' => 'currencies',
        'field' => 'name',
         'message'=> ('this currency name already exists in our DB'),
    );



    // Exclude if a id is given (edit action)
    if (isset($data['id'])) {
        $options['exclude'] = array('field' => 'id', 'value' => $data['id']);
    }



    // Validate that name  is not already in use
    $this->getElement('name')
            ->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, $options

    );



    return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

Will any body guide me how can I validate duplication on combined fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready to use validator for this, as far as I know. You have either to write your own, or do a check with SQL-query with three conditions (one for each field).

Answer (score 0):

you have to Apply a validation on name element of zend form.
Here is code for add validation on name field.

```
$name->addValidator(
    'Db_NoRecordExists', 
    true, 
    array(
        'table' => 'currencies',
        'field' => 'name',
        'messages' => array( "recordFound" => "This Currency Name already exists in our DB") ,

    )
);
```

And you must set required true.